# Check Console Output In Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit, moq

Is there a way I can check what is the output to the console in my unit test of my abstract class Question?

I am using NUnit & Moq.

My unit test looks like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void QuestionAsk()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<Question>(new object[]{"question text",true});

        mock.CallBase = true;

        var Question = mock.Object;

        Question.Ask();

        mock.Verify(m => m.Ask(), Times.Exactly(1));

    }
```

Here I am checking that Question.Ask() is called and it works fine.  Ask() does not return a value so I cannot assign it to a variable.  The function just outputs to the console.

Is there a way I can verify in the test that the output == "question text" ?

EDIT: Forgot to mention Question is an abstract base class.

I tried the Concole.Setout method suggested with this code:

```
    [Test]
    public void QuestionAsk()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<Question>(new object[]{"question text",true});

        mock.CallBase = true;

        var Question = mock.Object;

        using (var consoleText = new StringWriter())
        {
            Console.SetOut(consoleText);
            Question.Ask();
            Assert.That(consoleText.ToString(), Is.StringMatching("question text"));
        }
        mock.Verify(m => m.Ask(), Times.Exactly(1));

    }
```

But it took 236 ms which is far too long for a test.  Implementing the IWriter interface seems the best way to deal with it so I will give that a go now.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852862/mocking-system-console-behaviour.

Comment: Besides @Keith's link, you don't actually want to call console from your Question "business object". It's the running program's task to perform the output, because you now cannot reuse this class for, say, a web application. If you just let it return the string, the calling program can decide how to output it.

Comment: @CodeCaster Good point.  I will be eventually porting this to web so I should take care of that sooner rather than later.  I am doing this project to learn C#.  I really appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can initialize `Question` with a custom output writer, and then mock the writer to verify the output:

```
public interface IOutputWriter 
{
    void WriteLine(string s);
}

// Use this console writer for your live code
public class ConsoleOutputWriter : IOutputWriter
{
    public void WriteLine(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

public abstract class Question
{
    private readonly IOutputWriter _writer;
    private readonly string _text;
    private readonly bool _default;

    public Question(IOutputWriter writer, params object[] args)
    {
        _writer = writer;
        _text = (string)args[0];
        _default = (bool)args[1];
    }

    public void Ask()
    {
        _writer.WriteLine(_text);
    }
}


[Test]
public void QuestionAsk()
    {
        var writer = new Mock<IOutputWriter>();

        var mock = new Mock<Question>(writer.Object, new object[]{"question text",true});

        mock.CallBase = true;

        var Question = mock.Object;

        Question.Ask();

        mock.Verify(m => m.Ask(), Times.Exactly(1));
        mock.Verify(w => w.WriteLine(It.Is<string>(s => s == "question text")), Times.Once)

    }
```

Comment: Thanks this seems the best way to do it.  I initiatlly liked the Console.SetOut method as it just needs a single line of code to my existing tests but it made my test go from 6ms to 236ms.  This would cripple me as I plan on having lots of tests.  Is this performance decrease normal with SetOut or could I have done something wrong?  Is it ok to paste my code in as an answer or do I have to make a new question for that?  Sorry I am still new here

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question.

Comment: I suspect the last line `mock.Verify(w => w.WriteLine(It.Is<string>(s => s == "question text")), Times.Once)` should be `writer.Verify(w => w.WriteLine(It.Is<string>(s => s == "question text")), Times.Once)`. Another issue, `Ask` in the `Question` class should be `virtual`.

Answer (score 3):

Your test looks very strange - you are exercising mocked object instead of testing some real object which will be used by your application. If you are testing `Question` object, then you should use exactly same instance of `Question` type, as your application would use. What should be mocked - dependencies of `Question`. Because classes should be unit-tested in isolation (otherwise problems with dependencies would result in failing tests of `Question` which works fine).

So, if you have `Question` which displays something on console (i.e. it depends on `Console`), then unit-testing requires mocking of this dependency. You can't mock `Console` with Moq, because it's static class. Thus you should create abstraction for console, which will be used by `Question`:

```
public interface IConsole
{
    void Write(string message);
}
```

Now inject this dependency to your `Question`:

```
public class Question
{
    private IConsole _console;
    private string _message;

    public class Question(IConsole console, string message)
    {
        _console = console;
    }
}
```

With this code you can write tests for `Question` behavior:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldAskQuestionOnConsole()
{
    var message = "Hello World";
    var consoleMock = new Mock<IConsole>();
    consoleMock.Setup(c => c.Write(message));
    var question = new Question(consoleMock.Object, message);

    question.Ask();     

    consoleMock.VerifyAll();
}
```

This test specifies, that question should send its message to console, when `Ask` is executed. Implementation is simple:

```
public void Ask()
{
    _console.Write(_message);
}
```

Now you have working `Question`. And you should implement `IConsole` which will be used by your application. It's simple wrapper:

```
public class ConsoleWrapper : IConsole
{
     public void Write(string message)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(message);
     }
}
```

In your real application inject this implementation to question (this will can be done automatically by dependency injection framework):

```
IConsole console = new ConsoleWrapper();
Question question = new Question(console, message);
```

Notes: I'd go with some interface like `IView` instead of `IConsole`. That will completely abstract `Question` class from type of `UI` it works with. And second note is separating of business logic from presentation logic. Usually you don't have class which is responsible for two things - holding data of question (and possibly processing it), and interacting with user. Usually there is something like controller, which receives user input, refreshes UI and asks business model for data.

Comment: Sorry I should have made clear, Question is an abstract class.